# What is correct way to open App in AppStore

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone

Im trying to open app page in Apple AppStore app on iOS Devices from  AngularJs website.

Upon searching I came to know there are 3 ways of opening app page on apple appstore:

This will first open browser then it will ask you to whether to open it ion appstore app:

> http://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8

Following 2 ways opens app page in appstore directly but Im not sure which one will work for all iOS Versions / Devices and which one will not:

> itms://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8

or this way:

> itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8

Im confused which one to use for my project and whether if there is any better way to do this?

Comment: This is something I'm interested in knowing too

Comment: Lets see if we can get answers :)

Answer (score 1):

itms-apps:// actually works again in iOS10,
itms-apps:// no longer works in iOS5 and above. Just use

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id375380948?mt=8
and there are no more redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8
```

It works with iOS 10 and thats a big deal as you covered almost 99.9% of iOS devices according to this stats:

https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/